# Is there any better way to get mac address from arp table?

Tags: linux, algorithm, bash, awk, arp

I want to get a mac address from arp table by using ip address. Currently I am using this command

```
arp -a $ipAddress | awk '{print $4}'
```

This command prints what I want. But I am not comfortable with it and I wonder if there is any built-in way or more stable way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse the `/proc/net/arp` file using `awk`:

```
awk "/^${ipAddress//./\.}\>/"' { print $4 }' /proc/net/arp
```

but I'm not sure it's simpler (it saves one fork and a subshell, though).

If you want a 100% bash solution:

```
while read ip _ _ mac _; do
    [[ "$ip" == "$ipAddress" ]] && break
done < /proc/net/arp
echo "$mac"
```

Comment: nice answer. But I think if awk fails,the same reason (column order change etc.) probably causes to bash code fails. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ibrahim You're absolutely right. If one day some guy decides there should be some change in the `/proc/net/arp` file, your code will fail miserably. Now is this likely to happen anytime soon? Who knows... The safest way is of course to use the ARP protocol directly using a wrapper library. But this will work until the library API is changed by some guy who decides it should... Anyway, I'd say you'll be safe for some time using either method.

Comment: The linux kernel guys like to keep their external API stable -- as stated in my answer, it is the same source of information as `arp` uses.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could write a program (such as in C) to actually use the ARP protocol (yes, I *know* that's redundant, like ATM machine or PIN number) itself to get you the information but that's likely to be a lot harder than a simple pipeline.

Perhaps you should examine your comfort level a little more critically, since it's likely to cause you some unnecessary effort :-)

The [manpage for the Linux ARP kernel module](http://linux.die.net/man/7/arp) lists several methods for manipulating or reading the ARP tabes, `ioctl` probably being the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `arp -a` is locale dependent (i.e. it changes with your system language). So it might be a good idea to at least force it to the default locale:

```
LC_ALL=C arp -a $ipAddress | awk '{print $4}'
```

However, I share your fear that the output of `arp -a` is not meant to be parsed. If your program is restricted to linux system, another option would be to parse the file `/proc/net/arp`. This file is exported by the kernel and is what arp itself parses to get its information. The format of this file is described in the manpage proc(5), see `man 5 proc`.
This can be easily done with awk:

```
awk '$1==IPADDRESS {print $4}' /proc/net/arp
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk + sed solution which doesn't assume the column number is always 4.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /proc/net/arp |\
    # remove space from column headers
    sed 's/\([^ ]\)[ ]\([^ ]\)/\1_\2/g' |\
    # find HW_address column number and/or print that column
    awk '{
        if ( !column ) {
            for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
                if ( $i ~ /HW_address/ ) { column=i }
            };
            print $column
         }
         else {
            print $column
         }
    }'
```

There are still fragile assumptions here, such as the column name being "HW address".

Answer (score 0):

Update, removed PIPE

```
sed -nr 's/^'${ipAddress//./\.}'.*(([0-9A-Za-z]{2}:){5}[0-9A-Za-z]{2}).*$/\1/p' /proc/net/arp
```

Solution for non-fixed column;

```
arp -a $ipAddress | sed -n 's/^.*\(\([0-9A-Z]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[0-9A-Z]\{2\}\).*$/\1/p'
```

**Explanation**

- `^.*` - Match start of string `^` followed by any character `.*`.
- `[0-9A-Z]\{2\}:` - Match any character of numeric alpha-numeric twice followed by colon.
- `\([0-9A-Z]\{2\}:\)\{5\}` - Match the pattern between the `( )` five times.
- `[0-9A-Z]\{2\}` - Match any character of numeric alpha-numeric twice.
- `.*$` - Match any characters zero or more times `.*` until end of string `$`.
- `\1/p` - Return capture pattern 1 / `p` print the match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one for scripting:

```
awk ' $1~/[[:digit:]]/ {print $4}' /proc/net/arp
```

what it do:

1. read /proc/net/arp (standard arp output)
2. searchig for strings with [0-9]
3. get the 4rd "column" with mac adresses

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the `arping` command to explicitly query the MAC of some IP address (this also updates the local ARP cache):

```
 arping -c 1 192.168.2.24 | grep -Eo "([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]"
```

It's very useful to find if there exist two or more hosts using the same IP address (add -D option), or to check the current IP addresses used in the local VLAN with a simple script like:

```
for i in $(seq 1 254); do 
    IP="192.168.5.$i"
    MAC=$(arping -c 1 $IP | grep -Eo "([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]")
    if [ "$MAC" ] ; then
        echo "$IP $MAC"
    fi
done
```

Note that `arping` can't detect the IP address of the local host in this way (but we can add checks in the script to show it if exists in the range).

There exist several versions of `arping` with slightly different options and output. In Linux Ubuntu there are one in the package *iputils-arping* and other in the package *arping*.

Note: To answer the question and not the problem, when filtering `/proc/net/arp` you must use a regex that ensures the full match, like ending the expression with a space (otherwise, in this example, it will show also 2.240-2.249 addresses if present):

```
ipaddress="192.168.2.24"
grep "^${ipaddress} " /proc/net/arp | grep -Eo "([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]")
```